# xlwings - python - TypeError - image object

Tags: python, xlwings

I have an xlwings function (`ChartXYZ()`) that has been working without an issue.  It would produce the matplot image in excel.

I've now added a second xlwings function (`ChartSomethingElse()`), that also adds another matplot image. I've made sure not to name the new image the same as the old one.

The issue is - I now get the following error on my FIRST function (`ChartXYZ()`):

> TypeError: Don't know what to do with that image object

The 2nd function (`ChartSomethingElse()`), works no problem and produces the matplot.

Function One:

```
@xls.func
def plotHistData(ticker,field,startDate,endDate):
        df = histdata(ticker,field,startDate,endDate)
        sht = xls.Book.caller().sheets.active
        fig = df.plot()
        sht.pictures.add(fig, name=ticker+' hist', update=True)
        return 'Plotted chart'
```

Function Two:

```
@xls.func
def plotSpreadData(tickerOne,tickerTwo,fieldOne,fieldTwo,startDate,endDate):
    df_1 = histdata(tickerOne,fieldOne,startDate,endDate)
    df_2 = histdata(tickerTwo,fieldTwo,startDate,endDate)

    diff = df_1.subtract(df_2)*100

    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[2,1])

    figure = plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(gs[0])
    plt.plot(df_1)
    plt.plot(df_2)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.annotate('%0.3f' % df_1.iloc[-1],xy=(1, df_1.iloc[-1]),xytext=(8,0),
                 xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), textcoords='offset points')
    plt.annotate('%0.3f' % df_2.iloc[-1],xy=(1, df_2.iloc[-1]),xytext=(8,0),
                 xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), textcoords='offset points')

    font = {'family' : 'sans-serif',
            'weight' : 'normal',
            'size'   : 8}

    plt.rc('font', **font)


    plt.subplot(gs[1])
    plt.plot(diff)
    plt.annotate('%0.2f' % diff.iloc[-1],xy=(1, diff.iloc[-1]),xytext=(8,0),
                 xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), textcoords='offset points')
    plt.rc('font', **font)

    sht = xls.Book.caller().sheets.active
    sht.pictures.add(figure, name=tickerOne + ' ' + tickerTwo +' spread', update=True)
    return 'Plotted spread chart'
```

Comment: How could we *possibly* suggest anything relevant when you haven't shown us any code? Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please include the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: fair.  added code.